# Adding multiple Additional options to QGIS Batch processing?

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-3, batch

How to add multiple additional options on qgis batch processing?

[image]

result is : GDAL command:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "COMPRESS=JPEG JPEG_QUALITY=75 PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR TILED=YES"
```

it should be

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co JPEG_QUALITY=75 -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES ....
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use the pipe character "`|`" to separate your options, so for your options you would use:

```
COMPRESS=JPEG|JPEG_QUALITY=75|PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR|TILED=YES
```

i.e

[image]

This is now [documented](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#translate-convert-format):

> For Batch Process: separate multiple options with a pipe character
> (|).

At the time this question was asked, this was not documented (the [docs](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterconversion.html#translate-convert-format) just contained "*put parameter description here*"), I worked it out by looking at the [source](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/GdalUtils.py#L444).

Comment: Yes it s true actually I found that later on the log file when building just once instead of using the batch processing. Thanks ;)

Comment: +1 point for you, -1 for whoever wrote that documentation

Comment: +100 points for whoever will add it as info to the dialog itself

Comment: Pull requests welcome :)