# GDAL merge within a QGIS model designer

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, gdal-merge

I am attempting to include GDAL's `merge` but having difficulty with the "Additional creation options" field. I would like to include both `COMPRESS=LZW` and `TILED=YES` however I cannot seem to find the formatting that satisfies. I have tried things like:

- `COMPRESS=LZW TILED=YES`
- `COMPRESS=LZW, TILED=YES`
- `'COMPRESS'=LZW, 'TILED'=YES`
- `{'COMPRESS':LZW, 'TILED':YES}`

and I receive the following sort of errors:

[image: Warning 6]
*Warning 6: 'LZW, TILED=YES' is an unexpected value for COMPRESS creation option of type string-select.

Warning 5: COMPRESS=LZW, TILED=YES value not recognised, ignoring.*

It seems to be parsing my inputs in the strangest ways. Admittedly, I have not kept an exhaustive list of my various inputs.

[image: drop down arrow at the end of field]

This drop down arrow appears to do nothing, as well.

In the GUI to run the algorithm the feature is well structured, as is the command line, but in this case I must bring `merge` into a model and cannot find the appropriate directions.

I have looked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372332/qgis-gdal-merge-not-working) and decided to try the dictionary format. [This](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#gdalmerge) made it seem like a simple string would work, so I added the comma separator. [This documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#gdal-createoptions) made it seem as though no comma should be necessary (see fig 9.15). The [GDAL.org entry](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html) did not really clear things up with `-co <NAME=VALUE>` not really revealing how to include more than one (again, through the model specifically, the command line format is known).

It seems as though "Additional creation options" is only meant to take a single option, and should not be pluralized. More likely, I just don't know how to formulate it. Please help.

Comment: Can you try typing in the "Additional command-line parameters [optional]": `-co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES`. Remove the stuff in your "Additional creation options [optional]".

Comment: Please include errors  (or warnings in this case) as formatted text in your question, rather than pictures. It makes it much easier to debug and will also help others find your question when searching for the error message.

Comment: @Zman3 this works, as we would expect. Should I (or you) just put this as the answer to the question and basically leave this as a model builder issue? Perhaps the input field being different from the others is the sign that there's just a small bug somewhere?

Comment: @Matt done, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways you can reach your desired output.

The first (specifically asked by the OP), is to use the `additional creation options`. The correct syntax is to separate the entries with the pipe "|" character (shift + \). Please reference this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317700/adding-multiple-additional-options-to-qgis-batch-processing).

`COMPRESS=LZW|TILED=YES`

The second, using the `additional command-line parameters`. I have seen this section used most since it ties into how users would enter the parameters into a shell or python script.

`-co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES`

Note: Some options will require the `-co`, while others require a different prefix and others non at all. Check out the [gdal documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html).

[image]

Comment: This solves the task for the user but does not explain what format to use in the "Additional creation options" field :(

Comment: The first example I gave is very close to what the OP asked for; could switch `DEFLATE` to `LZW`. I've found that this is a common problem especially with people newer to using gdal command-line parameters and wanted to show a couple examples on the kind of format they should be looking for.

Comment: Your answer is great! But OP asked for the dialog field one row higher, the "Additional *creation* options". It's fine if they are satisfied with modifying the "Additional *command-line* parameters" but *if* you know how to specify multiple options in that, it would be fantastic if you could also add it.

Comment: @bugmenot123, I apologize; I am unaware how to correctly format the "additional creations options". I do not have the option to enter in 'text' in that field. It only displays as a drop down menu. Here is one [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317700/adding-multiple-additional-options-to-qgis-batch-processing) I found, but I am unable to test it since I only have a drop down menu. Might have a different QGIS version...?

Comment: @Binks That post does in fact lead to the correct answer. The field within the model builder setup "Additional creation options" will accept multiple parameters by using the pipe "|" character. "COMPRESS=LZW,|TILED=YES" (no quotes) produces this output: "gdal_merge.bat -n 0.0 -ot Int16 -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES"

Comment: Thanks @Pictory, I'll update my answer, is there supposed to be a comma "," there or is it just the pipe "|" character?

Comment: @Binks Shoot, that comma is a typo, but I cannot edit my comment.